# All interval sequences mod integers

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, reference-request, modular-arithmetic

In music, an all-interval twelve-tone sequence is a sequence that contains a row of 12 distinct notes such that it contains one instance of each interval within the octave, 1 through 11. The more mathematical and general definition is as follows:

**Definition**: A sequence $x_1,\ldots, x_n$ is said to be an all-interval sequence mod $n$ if $x_i \not \equiv x_j \pmod n$ for all $1\leq i<j \leq n$ and $x_{j+1}-x_j \not \equiv x_{i+1}-x_i \pmod n$ for all $1\leq i<j \leq n-1$.

For example, the sequence $0,5,1,4,2,3$ is an all-interval sequence mod 6. There are exactly 2 such sequences mod 4, 4 such sequences mod 6, 24 of them mod 8, 288 of them mod 10, and they are given by the sequence [A141599](https://oeis.org/A141599).

I could not find much about this subject online. I have found a reference [Latin Squares ...](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2027267?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents) which connects this definition to Latin squares of certain type.

It can be easily shown that if $n$ is odd, there are no all-interval sequences mod $n$. For $n$ even, using a computer one can compute the number of all-interval sequences mod $n$ for small values of $n$ but one quickly reaches the computing power of a regular computer around $n=20$.

I would like to explore this topic and would appreciate any references you can share. I am in particular interested in reasonable lower bounds on the number of all-interval sequences mod $n$. Currently I can show that there are at least $\phi(n)$ all-interval sequences mod $n$ but this is a miserable lower bound compared to the actual values.

Comment: The most recent literature seems to be "Results on permutations with distinct difference property" https://cdm.ucalgary.ca/cdm/index.php/cdm/article/view/147 - I believe all-interval sequences are the same as *modular* DDP sequences

Comment: $2^{n-1}$ is established as a lower bound in  https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X02004600.

Comment: @AnubhabGhosal: that's for general DDPs, not modular DDPs

Comment: @Dap, a permutation of $[n]$ with DDP is the same as a sequence of $n$ distinct integers with DDP modulo $n$.